# Sublime Text 3: Exclude subdirectories in search

Tags: sublimetext3

I've found a lot of answer on excluding specific subdirectories in a **Ctrl+Shift+F** search in Sublime Text, but nothing that allows me to just search the current directory and no sub directories.

I've tried `<current folder>` and `my_folder/`, but they both search the sub directories which is not what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: does [this post on the ST forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-turn-off-subfolders-in-find-in-files/18795/7?u=kingkeith) help?

Comment: @KeithHall, it does help, would be a shame if that's the most efficient way, but I haven't found a simpler solution. Thanks

Comment: Simplest solution was: `my_folder/,-my_folder/*/`.  Thanks again @KeithHall

Comment: You can always right click the folder you want to search in the sidebar and select: find in folder.

Comment: @Ekkstein no, you cannot use 'find in folder' because it will not exclude subdirectories like OP is asking

Comment: @Ta946 You're right. I was thinking the wrong way around.